# Font shape undefined

Tags: fonts, shapes, powerdot

I have a problem with my Latex

```
\documentclass[style=fyma,
mode=present %handout
]{powerdot}
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{pst-ovl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newtheorem{tw}{Twierdzenie}
\newtheorem{deff}{Definicja)}
\newtheorem{dow}{Dowód}

\title{Prezentacja - Pochodne}
\author{Patrycja}
\date{18.11}

\begin{document}


My text..

\end{document}
```

The following message is issued:

```
warning:  No file OT4phv.fd on input line 18  (\begin{document})
Font shape|OT4/phv/m/n' undefined(Font) using 'OT4/cmr/m/n' instead
Rerun to get \pageLabels entry
```

What should I do ?

Comment: Many thanks for posting a complete MWE. When I run it on my system, which has TeXLive2014 installed, I actually get a *different* warning message, issued by the hyperref package, about an incorrect DVI driver option (whatever that may mean). Which TeX distribution to you have?

Comment: @Mico latex->dvipdfmx

Answer (score 7):

This is because the `powerdot` class issues a

```
\def\rmdefault{phv}
```

to redefine the default font as Helvetica, which has no support for the `OT4` font encoding used by the `polski` package by default.

You have to load the `polski` package with the option `T1`

```
\usepackage[T1]{polski}
```

to avoid the warning and having the `T1` font encoding, which characters are supported with the Helvetica font.

MWE

```
\documentclass[style=fyma,
mode=present %handout
]{powerdot}
\usepackage[T1]{polski}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{pst-ovl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newtheorem{tw}{Twierdzenie}
\newtheorem{deff}{Definicja)}
\newtheorem{dow}{Dowód}

\title{Prezentacja - Pochodne}
\author{Patrycja}
\date{18.11}

\begin{document}

Po załadowaniu pakietu zmienione zostają wewnętrzne kody \TeX a dla odnośnych
liter polskiego alfabetu w Nowym Układzie (T1)

(from the \verb|polski| manual, I don't know what it means)

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: when I write \usepackage[T1]{polski} I see warning: Rerun to get /Pagelabel entry

Comment: @PatrycjaKaszyca - That's just a warning, not an error. As per the suggestion, just rerun LaTeX to fully update `\Pagelabel`.

Comment: @Mico no, because in the manual is typeset `TEXa`

Comment: always the same :<

Comment: at the moment when I do presentations I see only 7 slides and did 10

Comment: @PatrycjaKaszyca Without any additional info, I can't help you...