# LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape ... long time issue ... never resolved

Tags: fontspec, shapes

The warning I've had in my LuaTex code for too long (and far toooo many failed searches), that I'd like to eliminate, involves the following:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/phv/sb/n' undefined
(Font)              using `T1/phv/b/n' instead on input line
```

I assume the 'sb' is for semi-bold; would either look to implement the appropriate 'sb' font shape, or eliminate the error that calls for the 'sb' font shape.

The applicable LuaTex code is:

```
  \usepackage[default]{fontsetup} % Loads The NewComputerModern FontFamily See\altnote{The New Computer Modern FontFamily v. 4.5, \url{}}:
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \usepackage[]{unicode-math} % this loads fontspec
  \defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
  \defaultfontfeatures[\rmfamily]{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=1}
    % xetex/luatex font selection
  \setmainfont[Numbers=Proportional,Numbers=OldStyle]{Alegreya}
  \setsansfont[]{Alegreya Sans}
  \setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Fira Code}
  \setmathfont[]{Libertinus Math}
```

Not essential, but if someone sees what I am blind to, would be appreciated as I'd love to reduce the size of my .log file.

Current SE posts, such as "LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape undefined" (1) and "Font shape undefined" (2) don't appear to address the issue.

Thank you.

(1) [LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape undefined](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/273133/latex-font-warning-font-shape-undefined)

(2) [Font shape undefined](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/222599/font-shape-undefined)

Comment: Using lualatex with fontspec: You can define a font family by picking individual font files. So if you always use the semibold (where bold would be), you can define the font family so that it picks the semibold font, as the bold shape. This may or may not be what you are trying to do. If it is, the fontspec manual shows how.

Comment: you should not be using T1 with luatex, please provide a test file that produced this message which is trying to access an 8 bit subset of semi-bold Helvetica

Comment: @rallg Thank you for your supersonic response. I am NOT an aficionado by any means at LaTeX (or LuaTeX as the case may be). I do not have a definitive need for any specific font shape ... my goal is to convey a message, not the specific font shape that is used to do so. Any additional solution that eliminates the hundreds (perhaps thousands) of entries in my .log file would be more than appreciated.

Comment: @David Carlisle ... ditto. Thank you. Do I need to prepare a complete MWE? (It's been a while since I reduced my 22k lines of code to ~100.)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Might it be that when fontspec cannot find a shape, then the error message says "T1" regardless of font encoding? I seem to recall seeing messages like that, even though I never use anything but TU (utf-8) with fontspec and lualatex.

Comment: @rallg
 ... If you need a MWE, I'll do so; but is there an adjustment to the setup code I  provided to see if there is a quick fix?

Comment: @rallg no it doesn't invent the encoding and it doesn't pull Helvetica out of thin air.

Comment: @RosesBouquet the code you provided does not seem in any way relevant, it uses neither T1 or Helvetica, just remove those lines one at a time and see if the message goes.

Comment: @David Carlisle
 ... Thank you. Let me give that a try (I'm just not sure what lines ur referring to ...) if not, I'll need time for the MWE. (Working that now ...) Thanks again!!

Comment: but those lines do not cause the message you show, so deleting them are unlikley to make it go. the fontsetup package does change some math settings which make some messages appear but they are not errors, and they are not the ones you show.,

Comment: Quick fix? Probably not. Fix? Surely. As David noted, the problem may have nothing to do with my original suggestion. That applies to strictly-fontspec methods, stricktly OpenType fonts, no mingling.

Comment: @rallg
 Thanks for the thought ... still attempting to reduce 22k lines of code to ~100 to 200 for MWE ... slow going. May have to do with my switch from PDFTex to LuaTex some time ago. Thanks again!!

Comment: the message is not an error it's a warning and quite likely has no effect on the actual output as it is correctly telling you that you don't have a semi bold helvetica in classic tex encoding, but hopefully you have set things up not to use classic 8 bit tex fonts in text anyway so you are just setting up some font you probably are not using in some code you have not shown.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thnaks for the clarification. I knew that TU was a kind of TeX encoding, but did not realize it was an alias of itf-8. And back the the original question: Apparently the OP has mixed encodings, or a font that is incompatible with the selected encoding? Beyond me, since I only use one.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I did follow. But my response was not elegant. Anyway, I am unable to emulate the situation raised by the OP. Now that I think of it, it seems likely that my previous confusion regarding T1 warnings with TU encoding, was due to experiments on my part.